Does Dragon Ball Z: Kakarot have ecchi scenes?
Does Dragon Ball Z: Kakarot have sexualised (ecchi) scenes like the anime and manga? How many? How often? What exactly?
Doesn't have to be exact, but whatever you remember will help. Compare to the amount of "ecchiness" present in the manga/anime.

E.g. Master Roshi begging to see panties; nose exploding when flashed; "girly magazines"; naked Goku peeing in a lake etc.


I am trying to guage how ecchi the game is, to make subjective decisions about it, so understand that I am not asking for an exhaustive answer, but something along the lines of

"there are a couple of scenes where x and y happens, and a couple of innuendoes such as z, but that's pretty much it, and most of it is skippable and overall there's much less than in the manga"


I am somehow struggling to take this question seriously. Anyway, I will just point out the game is about Dragon Ball Z, not Dragon Ball.

@SPArcheon-onstrike I seriously want to know if the game has ecchi scenes or not. Serious replies only please. As far as I've heard, it starts with a mini game where the player is tasked to look for Master Roshi's "girly magazines". That's already pretty ecchi.

Again, I don't get the purpose of the question. If you are asking because you fear you may feel uncomfortable with  some of the content I suggest you make it explicit in the question. Currently you are asking for a list of all "ecchi" scenes but I doubt someone would want to replay all the game to track all the scenes. If that helps you I can just point out that I don't remember anything as bad as the infamous beach scene in the first episodes of Dragonball but there are still multiple instances of "swimsuits" like for example closeups of the covers of said Roshi magazines

To put it more bluntly: I just doubt someone wants to make a complete "timeline" of a full let's play video to point out all the scene one may jump to to see "ecchi content".

I am not asking for that

I don't remember any "nose exploding when flashed" in either the game or the TV series -- only remember seeing that in One Piece and Naruto.

@DanielSchepler sorry but turns out your memory is incomplete. There were several nose exploding scenes in DBZ

Dragon Ball Z: Kakarot contains a few ecchi scenes
From the CommonSenseMedia review, under the "Sex, Romance & Nudity" header:

Several suggestive references, including Master Roshi being "pervy" and a "pervert," mention of a "risqué magazine," and another character who's talked about for his questionable actions toward women. An adult magazine is seen. Shows women with deep cleavage, but no nudity.

From the content guide of the GeeksUnderGrace review:

Sexual Content: Adult magazines are a collectible item in the game. One of these magazines are shown, and on it is a clothed woman with cleavage. One of the characters is called a pervert for collecting them.

And finally, from the ESRB rating summary:

The game contains some suggestive material: a menu screen depicting adult magazines (women with deep cleavage, no nudity); suggestive descriptions of items and characters (e.g., “A risqué magazine, stored away in a random capsule by Dr. Briefs”; “...he is...quite the pervert, oftimes getting himself into trouble with women"; “...expelled for stealing his teacher's underwear...he originally used his power to kidnap young women he liked."); in one sequence, a character is seen reading an adult magazine (no nudity).

My emphases.
Altogether I think this gives a decent idea of what sexually tinted content to expect.

Thanks, and especially thanks for those content guides. Very useful +1

Downvoter, please point out your problem with this answer, and I'll try to improve it.

Wasn't me, but I suspect it's because of the first line. You said "no ecchi scenes" and then procede to produce evidence of some ecchi scenes. Maybe you have a different definition of "ecchi" or "scene", but the first line in and of itself is up for debate

Thank for the reply, @RabbiKaii! I checked, and indeed had a different idea of ecchi, thinking it was more explicit. I'll edit it.

I've accepted this answer and will only unaccept it and accept another answer if that answer is from someone who has played the game, remembers all of it, and goes through all the scenes. A big ask, so I think your checkmark is safe :) Thanks again for the great answer

Maybe something to add: there is one side quest where Roshi gets a little bit ecchi in his description of a woman you'll be searching for, and only afterwards realizes he was talking to a young boy.
